# mongo db updating multiple subdocuments with value from parent document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to write a script to update subdocuments in my mongodb collection as follows:

```
1) add first_name & last_name fields to each answers array
2) populate those fields with the first_name & last_name values from the parsed answers name element.
```

I am having trouble because there doesn't seem to be a clear way to do this in mongo. What I want in pseudocode is:

```
db.questions.update({answers},{
$set{"answers.$.first_name":"questions.first_name","answers.$.last_name":"questions.last_name"},{"multi":"true"}})
```

Following is the data schema:

```
questions = {
"_id":ObjectId,
"user_id":ObjectId,
"first_name":string,
"last_name":string,
"title":string,
"profile_image_file":string,
"avatar_replacement_number":int,
"workspace_id":ObjectId,
"question":string,
"answer_count":int,
"answers": [{
    "_id":ObjectId,
    "user_id":ObjectId,
    "name":string,
    "title":string,
    "answer":string,
    "like_user_ids":[ObjectId],
    "created_datetime": {
        "d":string,
        "t":string
    },
    "is_active":boolean
 }],
 "created_datetime":{
 "d":string,
 "t":string
  },
 "is_active":boolean
}
```

Comment: Can you show the expected than output?

Comment: I want to add the fields "first_name":string,"last_name":string, to the answers array and populate them with the first and last names from the "name" field in the answers array. So expected output would be: "first_name":"Joe", "last_name":"Smith"

Comment: Is there any document stored in collection? which you want to update. It would be good if you can provide proper document instead of just string boolean and int.

Comment: yes, thanks. the document I'd like to update is "answers"[{ to add 1) "first_name": "name_first_part" 2)"last_name": "name_last_part"

Comment: @Dikesh update. I almost have it. Just have to get the update statement correct.                      `db.questions.find().forEach(function(g) {  
 if(g.answers && g.answers[0]){
 var namey = JSON.stringify(g.answers[0].name);

 var first_name = namey.split(" ")[0].substr(1);
 var last_name = namey.split(" ")[1].slice(0,-1);

 db.questions.update({ g: g.answers[0].name }, { $set: 
  { "answers.$.first_name": first_name , "answers.$.last_name": last_name } }, { multi:true }  )

  print(first_name);
  print(last_name);
 }
});`

Comment: @Dikesh I have the updates working with roughly the above code in a javascript script which I run via a load() function from the mongo shell. It updates the first instance of each answer name, inserting a first name and last name value, but still does not insert in the case of successive instances of answers by the same person.